# Creating Configurable product in Akeneo

Tags: akeneo

We wants to Create Configurable product in Akeneo.
Can anyone help me to how to create configurable product in Akeneo.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "configurable"? Can you explain a bit more the use cases you want to cover?

Comment: All products are configurable into the modelisation of there family. 

For add a new attribute for the product, create a new product, and add into the family of  this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Configurable product in Akeneo are called Product Models and can be created using the UI on the product grid. To be able to create one, you need to define a new family variant inside your existing families.